# Angular Strap Alert onShow function not firing

Tags: angular-strap

we have been using Angular-Strap alert service for alerts and now need to make them accessible by setting focus on the alert message after the alert opens.

I have tried adding an onShow function to the alert options, but The onShow function is not firing.

How can I get this to work?  Here is the option configuration

```
Itinerary.alertConflict = function () {
    if ($rootScope.conflictShown) return false;

    $rootScope.conflictShown = true;
    $rootScope.conflictAlert = $rootScope.showAlert({
        template: '/Content/views/alerts/exhibition-conflict.html',
        animation: 'am-fade-and-slide-top',
        placement: 'top',
        type: 'warn',
        show: true,
        onShow: function () {
            alert('TEST');
            $timeout(function() {
                var message = document.getElementById('alert');
                if (message  !== null) {
                    message .focus();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `bs-on-show="yourFunction"` attribute on your html element witch have `bs-alert` directive. `yourFunction` should be in scope.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible since angular-strap#2.3.9

Comment: Let me know to call a function if we want to use below #2.3.9 version.